# Is there any general rule of thumb for what would cause an "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)"?

Tags: java, exception

I have searched the internet for an answer to what could be causing "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)" in java but I couldn't find anything beyond reinstall your jvm. I know that it is a problem with my code, what in my code could cause this?

This exception always occurs directly after I have Created a Database Connection, and it always has to do with ntdll.dll.

Comment: ...reinstall your JVM. hehe, just kidding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that there was a crash, probably a null pointer access, in native code (C or C++) loaded by Java, in this case, probably a database driver. If you have access to the source code for the native library, you can try debugging it by attaching a native debugger (like Visual Studio) to the Java process before the crash occurs. Otherwise, you'll need to report a bug to whoever wrote the buggy native code. Note that it may not technically be a "bug" in the native code. It could be that your code is passing in a bad parameter and they're just not handling error checking very well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the JVM or the database driver or both. Maybe a different version will work?